# Cronjob - How to output stdout, and ignore stderr

Tags: python, bash, stdout, cron, stderr

Is it possible to output `stdout` to file, but ignore `stderr`?

I have a Python script that uses `sys.stderr.write(error)` to output errors to `stderr`. I'd like to ignore these for this particular script. How is this possible?

Here is the current entry in the crontab:

```
* * * * * /Users/me/bin/scrape-headlines /Users/me/proxies.txt >> /Users/me/headlines.txt 2>&1
```

`scrape-headlines` is a bash script that calls the Python script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `2>&1` redirects `stderr` to `stdout`, appending it to the `headlines.txt`.
So, redirect `stderr` to `/dev/null`:

```
* * * * * /Users/me/bin/scrape-headlines /Users/me/proxies.txt >> /Users/me/headlines.txt 2> /dev/null
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "2" descriptor to control `stderr` separately and, e.g., redirect it to `/dev/null`:

```
* * * * * /Users/me/bin/scrape-headlines /Users/me/proxies.txt >> /Users/me/headlines.txt 2>/dev/null
```

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect stderr and stdout separately.

```
$ command 1> /some/file 2> /some/other/file
```

If you want to drop stderr, send it to`/dev/null`.